# Cropping a bitmap considering display size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a large image (1024x1024) and want to crop it in order to fit screen correctly considering the display size (e.g. 480x800). However, as seen below, it doesn't fit. How can I fit it?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Point size = new Point();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(size);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.sample);
        Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        ImageView bg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgview);

        bg.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[image: Current view]
[image: Background image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use:

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) | [Github Source](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Example from their site:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView);
```

Play around with it and set your `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to fill the screen width

Comment: Picasso seems very useful. Thanks. If I couldn't find a solution, I will consider to use it.

Comment: It will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

In your ImageView tag add this:
`android:scaleType="centerCrop"` You can also try `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: By the way, it would be easier if you just set "android:src="@drawable..." to set your bitmap, instead of setting it by code on your onCreate method.

Comment: Thanks, but further requirements force me to do this way.

Comment: Try to change the scale programatically before setting the bitmap like this `setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType scaleType)`

Comment: I tried  ' bg.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); '  and center_crop but it didn't help too.